# Is this a array or not?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I have this array filled with data from a database

```
$collectTable1 = array( 'errand' => $interest->errand_id,
                        'timestamp' => $interest->timestamp,
                        'type' => $interest->type,
                        'amount' => $interest->amount
                    );

$collector[] = $collectTable1;
```

And i want to rsort the timestamp, like this

```
$sortTime = rsort($collectedData['timestamp']);
```

I tried this, and i get this output

```
 function timesort($a, $b) {


 return (intval($a['timestamp']) > intval($b['timestamp']));
}

usort($collector, "timesort");
```

2017-12-01 10:53:26

I tought i would get from the descending date point? Something like 
2018-09-04 12:32:16.

My timestamp also contains both unixtimestamp and regular dates like this "
2017-12-01 10:53:26"

Comment: use `rsort($collectedData)` as `$collectedData['timestamp']` is single value not an array instead `$collectedData` is an array

Comment: Dont know, what is `$collectedData`? Could it be a TYPO of `$collector`

Comment: you can use `is_array` to check - https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

Comment: I think you probably mean you want to sort the array on timestamp and not as you are attempting to do.... sort the timestamp

Comment: Probably you are only retaining one row of data from the DB, this looks like the symptom of a bigger issue.  `I have this array filled with data from a database` when you fetch the data use `fetchAll` or make sure your adding it with `$collectTable1[] = $row`  in "typically" a while loop  Or just sort the data with the SQL query itself (which wont solve the "possible" fetching issue)

Comment: Where are you defining `$collectedData`?

Comment: They are probably still working with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086327/array-wont-nestle-another-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Comment: @Pontus Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: @DavidWinder No i did not manage it:P Still trying tho!

Comment: @DavidWinder i edited my question  :P

Comment: @Pontus Sorry - I still cannot fully understand your question... what is your desire output? please post your full code and maybe I will be able to find the problem

Comment: @DavidWinder All i want is to sort the timestamp from the latest(Desc) to the oldest time So from 2018-11-01 to the oldest datetime in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guessing you have array of element in `$collector`.

If you want to sort those by the `timestamp` you can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Consider the following example:

```
$collector = array();
$e1 = array("errand" => 1, "timestamp" => "2017-12-01 10:53:26");
$e2 = array("errand" => 2, "timestamp" => "2018-07-01 10:53:26");
$e3 = array("errand" => 3, "timestamp" => "2018-12-01 10:53:26");

$collector = array($e1, $e2, $e3);

function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return (strtotime($a['timestamp']) < strtotime($b['timestamp']));
}

usort($collector, "cmp");
```

When your `timestamp` values are in string use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert them to EPOC before compare.

Now, the `$collector` array elements are sorted by the `timestamp` value.

Output of the code example is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [errand] => 3
            [timestamp] => 2018-12-01 10:53:26
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [errand] => 2
            [timestamp] => 2018-07-01 10:53:26
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [errand] => 1
            [timestamp] => 2017-12-01 10:53:26
        )
)
```

Comment: I think they want a reverse sort on the timestamp.

Comment: Not sure if the updated version is much better - your still using `strcmp()`

Comment: Dump the sorted array, so we can see what it does.

Comment: Added the output and update the code without `strcmp`

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your array:

```
<?php

$data = [
    ['timestamp' => '100'],
    ['timestamp' => '300'],
    ['timestamp' => '200']
];

usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    return $b['timestamp'] <=> $a['timestamp'];
});

var_export($data);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 
    array (
    'timestamp' => '300',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
    'timestamp' => '200',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
    'timestamp' => '100',
    ),
)
```

Comment: @splash58, it's all useful information to the answer as OP or future readers may have earlier versions of PHP (although I hope that will improve)

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple value for all key of associative array $collectTable1 than

```
foreach($interest as $i){
$collectTable1 = array( 'errand' => array($i->errand_id),
                        'timestamp' => array($i->timestamp),
                        'type' => array($i->type),
                        'amount' => array($i->amount)
                    );


rsort($collectTable1[‘timestamp’]);
```

Here collectTable1 is an associative array of one dimensional arrays ie.

> $collectTable1[‘timestamp’][0]=firstvalue
>   $collectTable1[‘timestamp’][1]=secondvalue

And so on

Comment: Can we have a demo please?

Comment: I assume that $interest is an dataset for some query like $interest=“ SELECT * FROM interests_table” or some thing like that